# How to catch the <mat-error> error message text content using Protractor

Tags: angular, testing, protractor, automated-tests, e2e-testing

I'm dealing with below element and having trouble with getting the error message text in to a variable.

```
<mat-error _ngcontent-c16="" class="mat-error ng-star-inserted" id="error-email-required" role="alert" style=""> Email is a required field </mat-error>
```

Catching the element is straight forward.

> var emailReqiredLabel = element(by.id('error-email-required'));

I tried below options but all printing as >> visible error message is : [object Object]

- var errormsg = emailReqiredLabel.getText().toString();
- var errormsg = emailReqiredLabel.getAttribute('value').toString();

  console.log("visible error message is : " + errormsg );

can someone advice please.

Comment: console.log("visible error message is : " + JSNO.stringify(errormsg )); for starters.

Answer (score 0):

`mat-error` does not show up by default. It only shows when the input is touched. So before getting the text try to click on the field and try `getText()`. If that does not work try `JSON.Stringify(errormsg)`.

Comment: You are correct, I'm getting this at a validation point, at the time of execution this validation message is visible , when I try you'r solution I m getting "Failed: Converting circular structure to JSON". any clue on this

Comment: Did u try `getText()` after clicking and try to console the text.

Comment: `npm install --save circular-json` run this in your project location. And import the same in your spec file. then use`CircularJSON.stringify(errormsg);`