# How to test that component template contains mat-error

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-material-7

I want to create test for component that checks that mat-error is displayed.

I've created a test but it's failing because DOM does not have mat-error at all during testing. Although it works fine when project is served.

Template snippet

```
<mat-error>
    Error message
</mat-error>
```

Test set up

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        MatFormFieldModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule
      ],
      declarations: [MyComponent]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  fit('should display error', () => {
    const matErrorEl: HTMLElement = 
    fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(MatError)).nativeElement;
    expect(matErrorEl).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**tldr; You have to touch the `FormControl` before any errors will show.**

---

You have to first touch the component.
Using reactive forms (where `nameFormControl` is of type `FormControl`):

```
component.nameFormControl.markAsTouched();
```

Your `mat-error` element will now show in the view.

---

For a real scenario you will have an `ngIf` on the `mat-error` element and will need to set that error as well.

**Example template:**

```html
<mat-error *ngIf="nameFormControl.hasError('required')">
    Error message
</mat-error>
```

**Adding error:**

```
component.nameFormControl.setErrors({ required: true} as ValidationErrors);
```

---

Similar issue for this question:
[How to catch the <mat-error> error message text content using Protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52361190/how-to-catch-the-mat-error-error-message-text-content-using-protractor)

Official docs on Angular Form Validation:
https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#why-check-dirty-and-touched

Answer (score 1):

I followed an other way, I utilized a library named spectator for help me with scenarios using angular-material [spectator](https://github.com/ngneat/spectator)

file test

```
import { createComponentFactory, Spectator } from '@ngneat/spectator';
describe('InputEmailComponent', () => {
 let spectator: Spectator<InputEmailComponent>;
 const createComponent = createComponentFactory({
   component: InputEmailComponent,
 });

 beforeEach(() => (spectator = createComponent()));

 it(`should get the component mat-error with a email empty`, () => {
   // Pass a value null for a email validator required
   spectator.component.email.setValue(null);

   expect(spectator.query('mat-error')).toHaveText('Insira um e-mail válido');
 });

});
```

file component

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import {
  ControlContainer,
  FormControl,
  FormGroupDirective,
  Validators,
} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: "input-email",
  templateUrl: "./input-email.component.html",
  viewProviders: [
    {
      provide: ControlContainer,
      useExisting: FormGroupDirective,
    },
  ],
})
export class InputEmailComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() style: string = "";
  email: FormControl;
  constructor() {
    this.email = new FormControl("", [Validators.required, Validators.email]);
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {}

  getErrorMessage(): string | null {
    if (this.email.hasError("required") || this.email.hasError("email")) {
      return "Insira um e-mail válido";
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

file template html

```
<mat-form-field [style]="style" appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>e-mail</mat-label>
  <input
    type="email"
    formControlName="email"
    matInput
    placeholder="digite seu e-mail"
  />
  <mat-error *ngIf="!email.valid">{{ getErrorMessage() }}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue the other day working with the [angular testing-library](https://testing-library.com/docs/angular-testing-library/intro/) and Jest. The answer of @RonanCodes actually brought me on the right track. I had to add the `detectChanges()` statement after the `markAsTouched()` as well, though.

Admittedly, my setup is a bit different, since the date picker is a separate shared component, where you can inject a map of errors to handle depending on the validator functions that you added to the form control.

Anyways, in any case that adding `markAsTouched` does not resolve your issue, try adding `detectChanges` as well.

```
it('should show error', async () => {
    const reqMsg = 'This field is required';
    const errors = new Map([['required', reqMsg]]);
    const control = new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]);
    const rc = await renderComponent('ariaLabel', 'label', control, errors);
    
    control.setErrors({ required: true });
    control.markAsTouched();
    rc.detectChanges();
    
    expect(screen.getByTestId('date-picker-error')).toHaveTextContent(reqMsg);
  });
```